# MS Word macro - use system variable for template path

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a template that contains several macros, this template will be distributed on several devices.

I have the following macros to insert a text using quick parts of ms word.

```
Application.Templates( _


"C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP\template_name.dotm" _
    ).BuildingBlockEntries("alphabet").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, _
    RichText:=True
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
```

The issue is, the code contains the absolute path to the template, which won't be the same on different machines.

I have tried using `%Appdata%` instead, but there macro did nothing, with no error messages.

is there any way around this ?

Thank you

Comment: How do you get %Appdata% ? Do you use Environ("Appdata")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Environmental Variables in your VBA code to get the 'UserName'  i.e.

```
"C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\AppData\Roaming\.."
```

Here is one link to show other variables (or just search for 'VBA using environmental variables' (without quotes:  https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s387/environment-variable-vba.htm

Comment: I was using `%appdata%` in the path directly, thinking it will expanded. 
didn't know about `Environ`, thank you!